# i am getting.JSONException: Unterminated object in android

Tags: android, special-characters, url-encoding, urldecode

I have an `EdiText` i want to send it over web by using `queryString`(includes also special characters),I have used `urlEncoder` for it.

But when i am getting the entered text back from the web ,it gives me `org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character error,It gives me error especially when i entered " "(comma) and single ' ' in request url,my code is as below`.

Please help me how to get comma and single coma from web without any exception in android.

**main.java**

```
public class ChatHistoryActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONArray msgArry;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    private ChatAdapter chatContent;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> msgList;
    ListView lv;
    JSONArray msgs = null;
    String pro_id, pro_name, pro_img, grup_id, sender_id, cust_id;
    TextView tv_switch;
    public boolean flag = false;
    Header header;
    Menu menu;
    Intent in;
    Button reply;
    RelativeLayout rl_reply;
    EditText et_reply;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_history);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv_switch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_switch);
        header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.header_msg);
        menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menu_msg);
        reply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reply);
        rl_reply = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_reply);
        rl_reply.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_reply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_reply);
        menu.setSelectedTab(3);
        header.title.setText("Conversation");
        msgList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        pro_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
        sender_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
        grup_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_GROUP_ID);
        cust_id = Pref.getValue(ChatHistoryActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");

        /* new GetChatHistory().execute(); */

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                rl_reply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });
        // message reply ...!!Chat api(conversation)
        reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DoReply().execute();
                // new GetChatHistory().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new GetChatHistory().execute();
    }

    private class GetChatHistory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_CHAT_HISTORY;
            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&sender_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id;

            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::in chat" + url);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    msgArry = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    if (msgArry != null && msgArry.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts

                        System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + msgArry.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < msgArry.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = msgArry.getJSONObject(i);

                            String custID = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                            String custName = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME);
                            String proID = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                            String email = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
                            String photo = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PHOTO);
                            String msg_body = c.getString(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY);
                            /*msg_body = URLDecoder.decode(msg_body, "utf-8");*/
                            HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID, custID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, custName);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, email);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PHOTO, photo);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY, msg_body);

                            msgList.add(message);

                        }
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "No messgaes found", "yehki", "Ok");
                                msgList.clear();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::inside post:::::::::::");
            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);

            et_reply.setText("");

        }
    }

    /*
     * GET CONVERSATION LIST.........REPLY
     */
    private class DoReply extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_MESSAGE_REPLY;
            String msg = et_reply.getText().toString().trim();

            try {
                msg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "utf-8");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&receiver_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id + "&message=" + msg;
            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::in doreply" + url);

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::get chat history called:::::::::::::;;");
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    if (jsonObj.getString("status").equals("sucess")) {
                        // et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has not been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::inside post:::::::::::");
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();

            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);

            lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);

            msgList.clear();
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            new GetChatHistory().execute();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give us the String that you're trying to parse ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma - yep i am giving you url below:http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/message.php?customer_id=41&group_id=2&sender_id=4&product_id=72

Comment: @Jigarjims Your JSON is not valid. Use JSON Lint for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the error is, because " is a special character for JSON. You'll need to escape the quotes.

```
{
    "customer_id": "41",
    "product_id": "72",
    "message_body": ""'"",  //Error 
    "customer_name": "Jigar makwana",
    "email": "jigar@epagestore.com",
    "photo": "upload/jimmy.jpg"
}
```

Also, this : [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)