# Single Quote Doesnt working while pass data to json in android

Tags: android, json, string

I am working on application in which I need to pass all the data send to server via json array at exact user had passed.

But My problem is When I pass Single quote message doesn't send to server.

I had tried.

```
text=text.replaceAll("'","\'");
```

### But My problem is

1. When user press single quote message doesn't send.
2. When user press single quote two time only one single quote is send.

Please give solution for that.

Comment: What happen if you pass entire text as it is without replaceAll() ?

Comment: Message doesnt send with single quote. Same prob as I told in question.

Comment: can you post your string? becuse i had pass this data {'DeviceId':'bf36d1c0-3c6c-43df-92c1-584666dc1007','DateIn':'2013/11/21','TimeIn':'12:05','Distance':'7'}, it's working

Comment: yup string is any thing. its user defined. but I cant pass Single quote(')

Comment: If we can not find solution you can use a Base64-encoding of a user message

Comment: @PoojaRoy, Use UTF-8 when you post the msg

Comment: @SwetaSharma still not working single quote

Comment: can you try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json

Comment: Base-64 doesn't work for you.

Comment: @PankajAndroid had done as the question says but still the prob is same. :'(

Comment: Try please &#39 for single quotes

Comment: Not worked @DenisMath

Comment: What exactly do you mean it does not send? The message does not leave the phone or the server does not accept it? This is clearly an escape problem because if you use two quotes one is "sending." Please post (1) where you are building the JSON that you are sending (2) where you sever is receiving it (3) any relevant setting on the server e.g. magic quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `replaceAll("'","\'");` to `replaceAll("'","\\u0027");`

**EDIT:**

`\u0027` is the unicode representation of `'`. Except in rare cases, unicode representations can be used in place of troublesome characters like `'`,`"`,`@`,`?`, and `&`.

You are likely losing your single quote characters because your json is going through multiple  layers of serialization/deserialization that are outside your control.

Comment: Can you explain why that would help?

Comment: Edited the answer to include. Thank you @mabi for the suggestion; I may have written the original answer in haste.

Comment: Thanks, much better. That said, UTF-8 sequences are replaced at compile time (refer to JLS 3.3), so the runtime effect would be all the same.

Comment: @mabi You are correct, so using UFT-8 in pre-compiled code would be virtually meaningless. The question targets JSON, however, which is by nature not going to interact with the compiler. Using Unicode substitutions is standard practice when serving JSON responses between applications.

Comment: Hm? The example code from the OP indicates he's using Java to transform some input. Your suggested (unicode escape) snippet compiles to the exact same bytecode used and marked as not solving the OPs problem.

Comment: He is transforming input, in the form of a literal string, at runtime. If you disagree with my assessment, feel free to write your own test program to determine whether it behaves the way I say or not. Or, if it is more fitting to your taste, write your own answer and allow the OP to choose. Nothing would give me more joy than seeing another well-explained answer to this conundrum.

Comment: As I said, (and I am legitimately not being sarcastic here), write another answer. If you can provide a working solution, we are all better off for it. I'll admit that most of my experience with JSON has been in Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, and C#, with only a few months working with Java. I would appreciate an opportunity to learn how to work around this (overly annoying and totally unnecessary) problem...