# Importing JSON into R with in-line quotation marks

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I'm attempting to read the following JSON file ("my_file.json") into R, which contains the following:

```
[{"id":"484","comment":"They call me "Bruce""}]
```

using the jsonlite package (0.9.12), the following fails:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(readLines('~/my_file.json'))
```

receiving an error:

```
"Error in parseJSON(txt) : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
84","comment":"They call me "Bruce""}]
           (right here) ------^"
```

Here is the output from R escaping of the file:

```
readLines('~/my_file.json')

"[{\"id\":\"484\",\"comment\":\"They call me \"Bruce\"\"}]"
```

Removing the quotes around "Bruce" solves the problem, as in:

my_file.json

```
[{"id":"484","comment":"They call me Bruce"}]
```

But what is the issue with the escapement?

Comment: `[{"id":"484","comment":"They call me "Bruce""}]` is not valid json http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ref: [Escaping quotation marks in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json) + try your JSON string in [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/). It won't parse with `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO` or `rjson`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In R [strings literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) can be defined using single or double quotes.
e.g.

```
s1 <- 'hello'
s2 <- "world"
```

Of course, if you want to include double quotes inside a string literal defined using double quotes you need to escape (using backslash) the inner quotes, otherwise the R code parser won't be able to detect the end of the string correctly (the same holds for single quote).
e.g.

```
s1 <- "Hello, my name is \"John\""
```

If you print (using `cat`¹) this string on the console, or you write this string on a file you will get the actual "face" of the string, not the R literal representation, that is :

```
> cat("Hello, my name is \"John\"")
Hello, my name is "John"
```

The json parser, reads the actual "face" of the string, so, in your case json reads :

```
[{"id":"484","comment":"They call me "Bruce""}]
```

not (the R literal representation) :

```
"[{\"id\":\"484\",\"comment\":\"They call me \"Bruce\"\"}]"
```

That being said, also the json parser needs double-quotes escaping when you have quotes inside strings.

Hence, your string should be modified in this way :

```
[{"id":"484","comment":"They call me \"Bruce\""}]
```

If you simply modify your file by adding the backslashes you will be perfectly able to read the json.

Note that the corresponding R literal representation of that string would be :

```
"[{\"id\":\"484\",\"comment\":\"They call me \\\"Bruce\\\"\"}]"
```

in fact, this works :

```
> fromJSON("[{\"id\":\"484\",\"comment\":\"They call me \\\"Bruce\\\"\"}]")
   id              comment
1 484 They call me "Bruce"
```

---

¹
the default R `print` function (invoked also when you simply press ENTER on a value) returns the corresponding R string literal. If you want to print the *actual* string, you need to use `print(quote=F,stringToPrint)`, or `cat` function.

---

**EDIT** (on @EngrStudent comment on the possibility to automatize quotes escaping) :

Json parser cannot do quotes escaping automatically.
I mean, try to put yourself in the computer's shoes and image you should parse this (unescaped) string  as json: `{ "foo1" : " : "foo2" : "foo3" }`

I see at least three possible escaping giving a valid json:
`{ "foo1" : " : \"foo2\" : \"foo3" }`
`{ "foo1\" : " : "foo2\" : \"foo3" }`
`{ "foo1\" : \" : \"foo2" : "foo3" }`

As you can see from this small example, escaping is really necessary to avoid ambiguities.

Maybe, if the string you want to escape has a really particular structure where you can recognize (without uncertainty) the double-quotes needing to be escaped, you can create your own automatic escaping procedure, but you need to start from scratch, because there's nothing built-in.

Comment: Thank you very much- very helpful.  I now see I am starting with invalid JSON.  However, I am dealing with a very large amount of data which is interspersed with this construction.  Is my only out to construct a little piece of code that searches for regex and correctly escapes the dataset?

Comment: @user3741038: yes I guess you should do something like that, even if I don't think it will be easy...

Comment: for large json is there a way to make the backslashes that is not manual?