# Change single backslash in R character string to valid JSON string

Tags: json, regex, r

I have a string in R which escapes quotation marks:

```
my_text = {\"stim\":[\"platery\",\"denial\",\"generic\"]}
```

When using `cat()` I get:

```
{"stim":["platery","denial","generic"]}
```

Now my whole string is a JSON string that needs to be parsed and is evaluated invalid by [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). If I copy&paste the `cat()` version, this is valid a JSON, so I think I just miss some pre-processing here.

I saw this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491986/r-gsub-replacing-backslashes), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r), [and this really good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245188/importing-json-into-r-with-in-line-quotation-marks), so I tried to replace the single quotation marks with double quotation marks for the JSON parser:

```
gsub("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\", my_text, fixed=TRUE)
```

but it did't change my string as I wanted. How can I change the string to become valid JSON?

Comment: You do not have any backslashes in your original string that is why *it didn't change my string*. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As Wiktor said your gsub didn't work because you are attempting to replace backslashes, but there aren't any backslashes in your string.  R is just using the backslashes as a way to store the double quotes.  The third SO post you link does a good job explaining R's string literals which addresses this.  A backslash in R is stored as a double backslash.

My first piece of advice would be to use the R package `jsonlite` to construct your JSON from an R object as opposed to a string if possible ([heres the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html)).

Example:

```
myJSON <- jsonlite::toJSON(list(stim=c("platery","denial","generic")))
# {"stim":["platery","denial","generic"]}
```

Second, (as the third SO post again does a good job of explaining) copying/pasting the print method of the string may not be the best way to validate the JSON.  I'm not sure of the use case, but R storing the double quotes with escape characters is probably not a bad thing.

If you want to get a prettier print method you can use numerous tricks in R (`noquote()`, `cat()`, `print(quote=F)`) but this won't change that R stores the double quotes with backslashes:

Additionally, in some cases constructing the JSON isn't necessary.  I have an API built using the `plumbr` package that returns a list as JSON without any modifications (`recJSON <- list(message=messages,recommendations=list(name=names, link=URLs))`)