# How to escape this multi-dimensional json array/string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a long json string that I send to the PHP server using AJAX post request. My problem is I really can't escape the strings or the values of the said json. Here is the json data

The PHP function on the HTML tab and the json on the JS tab.

The json above have already passed to json_decode function in php and var_dump.
Notice the data at `object['rest_data']['q25']['q25_others']` the data is `"25 others ""` and must be `"25 others \""`. I used this recursive function thinking that will do the work.

The `$this->Escape($value)` is with the same class with the recursive function that I use above. And the `Escape` function is just for escaping the strings that may cause SQL problems during insert.

Any suggestion.? I'm out of idea. Thanks!

```php
function deep_escape($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
      $this->deep_escape($value);
    } else {
      $array[$key] = $this->Escape($value);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

How I create the JSON

```js
all_get_data = {
  "q16": $('#survey_question_16').val(),
  "q17": {
    "q17_select": $('#survey_question_17').val(),
    "q17_others": $('#survey_question_17_others').val(),
  },
  "q18": {
    "q18_select": $('#survey_question_18').val(),
    "q18_others": $('#survey_question_18_others').val(),
  },
  "q19": $('#survey_question_19').val(),
  "q20a": $('#survey_question_20a').val(),
  "q20b": $('#survey_question_20b').val(),
  "q21": $('#survey_question_21').val(),
  "q22": $('#survey_question_22').val(),
  "q23": {
    "q23_select": $('#survey_question_23').val(),
    "q23_others": $('#survey_question_23_others').val(),
  },
  "q24": $('#survey_question_24').val(),
  "q25": {
    "q25_select": $('#survey_question_25').val(),
    "q25_others": $('#survey_question_25_others').val(),
  },
  "q26": {
    "q26_select": $('#survey_question_26').val(),
    "q26_others": $('#survey_question_26_others').val(),
  },
  "q27": {
    "q27_select": $('#survey_question_27').val(),
    "q27_others": $('#survey_question_27_others').val(),
  },
  "q28": {
    "q28_select": $('#survey_question_28').val(),
    "q28_others": $('#survey_question_28_others').val(),
  },
  "q29": {
    "q29_select": $('#survey_question_29').val(),
    "q29_others": $('#survey_question_29_others').val(),
  },
  "q30": "",
  "q31": $('#survey_question_31').val(),
  "q32": $('#survey_question_32').val(),
  "q33": {
    "q33_select": $('#survey_question_33').val(),
    "q33_others": $('#survey_question_33_others').val(),
  },
  "q34": $('#survey_question_34').val(),
};
```

Object dump

```php
array(5) {["part_i"]=>
  array(11) {["name"]=>string(0) ""
    ["permAdd"]=>string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>string(0) ""
    ["con_no"]=>string(0) ""
    ["mo_no"]=>string(0) ""
    ["civil"]=>NULL
    ["gender"]=>NULL
    ["bday"]=>string(0) ""
    ["region"]=>NULL
    ["province"]=>string(0) ""
    ["locationResidence"]=>NULL
  }
  ["part_ii"]=>array(3) {
    ["row1"]=>array(4) {
      ["el_1"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_2"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_3"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_4"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["row2"]=>array(4) {
      ["el_1"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_2"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_3"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_4"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["row3"]=>array(3) {
      ["el_1"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_2"]=>string(0) ""
      ["el_4"]=>string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["part_iii"]=>array(2) {
    ["erow1"]=>array(3) {
      ["eel_1"]=>string(0) ""
      ["eel_2"]=>string(0) ""
      ["eel_3"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["erow2"]=>array(3) {
      ["eel_1"]=>string(0) ""
      ["eel_2"]=>string(0) ""
      ["eel_3"]=>string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["part_iv"]=>array(2) {
    ["q15a"]=>array(3) {
      ["q15a_row1"]=>array(3) {
        ["q15a_el1"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el2"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el3"]=>string(0) ""
      }
      ["q15a_row2"]=>array(3) {
        ["q15a_el1"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el2"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el3"]=>string(0) ""
      }
      ["q15a_row3"]=>array(3) {
        ["q15a_el1"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el2"]=>string(0) ""
        ["q15a_el3"]=>string(0) ""
      }
    }
    ["q15b"]=>array(2) {
      ["q15b_select"]=>NULL
      ["q15b_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["rest_data"]=>array(20) {
    ["q16"]=>NULL
    ["q17"]=>array(2) {
      ["q17_select"]=>array(0) {}
      ["q17_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q18"]=>array(2) {
      ["q18_select"]=>NULL
      ["q18_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q19"]=>string(0) ""
    ["q20a"]=>string(2) ""'"
    ["q20b"]=>NULL
    ["q21"]=>NULL
    ["q22"]=>NULL
    ["q23"]=>array(2) {
      ["q23_select"]=>array(0) {}
      ["q23_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q24"]=>NULL
    ["q25"]=>array(2) {
      ["q25_select"]=>array(5) {
        [0]=>string(21) "Salaries_and_Benefits"
        [1]=>string(16) "Career_challenge"
        [2]=>string(25) "Related_to_special_skills"
        [3]=>string(22) "Proximity_to_residence"
        [4]=>string(5) "other"
      }
      ["q25_others"]=>string(11) "25 others ""
    }
    ["q26"]=>array(2) {
      ["q26_select"]=>array(0) {}
      ["q26_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q27"]=>array(2) {
      ["q27_select"]=>NULL
      ["q27_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q28"]=>array(2) {
      ["q28_select"]=>NULL
      ["q28_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q29"]=>array(2) {
      ["q29_select"]=>NULL
      ["q29_others"]=>string(0) ""
    }
    ["q30"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["q31"]=>
    NULL
    ["q32"]=>
    NULL
    ["q33"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["q33_select"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["q34"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

JSON structure

```js
{
  "part_i": {
    "name": "",
    "permAdd": "",
    "email": "",
    "con_no": "",
    "mo_no": "",
    "civil": null,
    "gender": null,
    "bday": "",
    "region": null,
    "province": "",
    "locationResidence": null
  },
  "part_ii": {
    "row1": {
      "el_1": "",
      "el_2": "",
      "el_3": "",
      "el_4": ""
    },
    "row2": {
      "el_1": "",
      "el_2": "",
      "el_3": "",
      "el_4": ""
    },
    "row3": {
      "el_1": "",
      "el_2": "",
      "el_4": ""
    }
  },
  "part_iii": {
    "erow1": {
      "eel_1": "",
      "eel_2": "",
      "eel_3": ""
    },
    "erow2": {
      "eel_1": "",
      "eel_2": "",
      "eel_3": ""
    }
  },
  "part_iv": {
    "q15a": {
      "q15a_row1": {
        "q15a_el1": "",
        "q15a_el2": "",
        "q15a_el3": ""
      },
      "q15a_row2": {
        "q15a_el1": "",
        "q15a_el2": "",
        "q15a_el3": ""
      },
      "q15a_row3": {
        "q15a_el1": "",
        "q15a_el2": "",
        "q15a_el3": ""
      }
    },
    "q15b": {
      "q15b_select": null,
      "q15b_others": ""
    }
  },
  "rest_data": {
    "q16": null,
    "q17": {
      "q17_select": [],
      "q17_others": [""]
    },
    "q18": {
      "q18_select": null,
      "q18_others": ""
    },
    "q19": "",
    "q20a": "'",
    "q20b": null,
    "q21": null,
    "q22": null,
    "q23": {
      "q23_select": [],
      "q23_others": ""
    },
    "q24": null,
    "q25": {
      "q25_select": [
        "Salaries_and_Benefits",
        "Career_challenge",
        "Related_to_special_skills",
        "Proximity_to_residence",
        "other"
      ],
      "q25_others": "25 others "
    },
    "q26": {
      "q26_select": [],
      "q26_others": ""
    },
    "q27": {
      "q27_select": null,
      "q27_others": ""
    },
    "q28": {
      "q28_select": null,
      "q28_others": ""
    },
    "q29": {
      "q29_select": null,
      "q29_others": ""
    },
    "q30": "",
    "q31": null,
    "q32": null,
    "q33": {
      "q33_select": []
    },
    "q34": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you create this JSON String and see its contents before it gets to PHP

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow

Comment: @RiggsFolly wait a sec sir ..

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already added how I create that json string ..

Comment: Don’t assemble JSON yourself. Built up a proper data structure (arrays/objects), and then use `json_encode` (PHP) or `JSON.stringify` (JS) to create proper JSON out of it. That will automatically take care of all necessary escaping. (As far as the context JSON is concerned. Why you bring SQL into it, is unclear. If you need to secure data before inserting it into the database, then you do that at the exact point where this database insert happens. To encode/escape the data for _this_ purpose earlier already is nonsense.)

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a NON Problem, just use `json_decode()` to convert the JSONStrng into a PHP array/Object

Comment: @RiggsFolly In the developer console of an webbrowser you can check the network tab and look for the request of the  ajax call that was made by the page. :)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yes you can. But why are you telling me?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your first comment!? But i really get your line after reading it 10 times... not my mother tongue ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions may because he can't see that code, only me the one who have the codes and want some clarification about this.?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yea, but at that point he had not posted his js code. And as I have not got the form I cannot do it for him

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, got it :)

Comment: @MerIgos Can I ask why you think there should be a trailing double quote in that field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks! Gonna check it now !

Comment: So maybe I should escape it first before sending to PHP?

Comment: In js, create an object. Then load all the data into properties of that object. Then use `JSON.Stringify()` on that object and the JSONString will be created properly. Or just pass the Object as your AJAX call parameter and it will all be looked after by better coders that us.

Comment: ^ lowercase `stringify`. But yes, that's it.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly says, better make an real javascript object and convert it via JSON.stringify(), that is the save way.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl didnt you mean `json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`?  -- _object from PHP into a proper JSON string_

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your function

```
function deep_escape($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
      $this->deep_escape($value); // <----------- This line does nothing.
    } else {
      $array[$key] = $this->Escape($value);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

See, you either want to be able to call your function like this

```
$instance->deep_escape($array);
```

and have the array be modified. In that case you need to declare it like this :

```
function deep_escape(&$array){                  // notice the '&'
  foreach($array as $key => &$value) {        // again '&'
    if(is_array($value)){
      $this->deep_escape($value);
    } else {
      $value = $this->Escape($value);
    }
  }
                                               // no "return" statement
}
```

Or you want to call it like this :

```
$escaped_array = $instance->deep_escape($array);
```

Which is the way I think you went for, in that case, you need to change that `line 4` of your function :

```
function deep_escape($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
      $array[$key] = $this->deep_escape($value);
    } else {
      $array[$key] = $this->Escape($value);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Nice but I think the point is that all this is unnecessary if the JSON String is created properly in the first place

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP never creates JSON, that is a dump for a PHP object. Don't get them confused. I added what I believe is the JSON structure at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I believe the JSON String is created properly by the JS part and properly parsed into an array with `json_decode()`. The point here is to escape potentially harmful strings before sending it to the database

Comment: @KiJéy Thank you for you answer, it helped me ^_^

Comment: @MerIgos always a pleasure ^_^ did it solve your problem ?

Comment: @KiJéy yep. Sorry for the late reply. But still, thank you !

Comment: No problem. You can set this answer as valid then if it answers the question correctly :p