# Python - Taking dictionary (hash input) as command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

There are some questions posted on the same topic regarding this but my concern is something else. 
I am trying to take dictionary input from command line and able to do it.

```
python sentence_scorev1.3.py "working today" "0.6" '[{"ques": "hello who are you", "ans": "I am rishabh", "type": 1},{"ques": "your name", "ans": "I am Ram", "type": 2},{"ques": "Are you working today", "ans": "Yes I am", "type": 4'}]'
```

I have taken the input and converted it into JSON and parse it using

```
json_data = json.loads(input_data)
```

where input data is the hash input. My concern is when I pass the same input with **'** punctuation in the hash input like **see your' in second ques key input**

```
'[{"ques": "hello who are you", "ans": "I am rishabh", "type": 1},{"ques": "your' name", "ans": "I am Ram", "type": 2}
```

It throws error as the python must have understood it as end of input but still I had input data string. Please let me know how to by-pass this.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @PaulCollingwood , its not about validating JSON, its about taking input from command line when ' punctuation id detected earlier than the actual input end

Comment: The point is not to expect your users to enter well formed JSON strings. You can enter such strings on the command line if you use escape characters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json

Answer (score 1):

If you're launching Python from a Unix shell or similar ...

The punctuation will be interpreted as the end of the third command line argument, which starts with the ' character to the left of the first square bracket.
To stop the shell from doing that, escape the ' with a backslash like this:

```
'[{"ques": "hello who are you", "ans": "I am rishabh", "type": 1},{"ques": "your\' name", "ans": "I am Ram", "type": 2}]'
```

(I tried to add balancing parentheses at the end.)

The parsing happens before Python even gets the command line arguments.

Edit:
The original command line includes an extra single quote. I think it should be like this:

```
'[{"ques": "hello who are you", "ans": "I am rishabh", "type": 1},{"ques": "your name", "ans": "I am Ram", "type": 2},{"ques": "Are you working today", "ans": "Yes I am", "type": 4}]'
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu terminal to execute and if I pass it as escape, it enters command line execution as :
>
>
and the script doesn't executes

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to include your sentence score Python script?

Comment: For now I have found a way. I will put # instead of ' in command line to take input. And in the script I have replaced # by '. For time being it can be used but not a correct approach. Looking for some genuine trick here

Comment: Another approach could be to create your JSON in a programmers' text editor that has syntax checking, then save it as a file, then read the file instead.