# Java jackson ObjectMapper fails when value contains double quotes?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have got java string(containing json object)

```
{"Attribute_1":""test"","Attribute_2":"100"}
```

When I covert to java object MyCustomClass i get runtime error because of double quotes around `test` .  I am not sure how to escape double quotes inside
json attribute value

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(requestData, MyCustomClass.class);
```

Error is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: {"Attribute_1":""test"","Attribute_2":"100"} line: 1, column: 12]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:437)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1795)
```

This is not a duplicate of [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json) by an chance as that is display issue

Comment: You escape it with backslash. `{"Attribute_1":"\"test\""`. If some webservice is giving you a json like that it should be corrected, the JSON is invalid.

Comment: Should `Attribute_1`'s value really be `"test"` rather than `test` ?

Comment: Anyway the problem is that when it has reached `{"Attribute_1":""`, the parser thinks it has read a key-value pair and complains that what follows isn't either a `,` or a `}`

Comment: @BackSlash From ui this is getting passed as only `{"Attribute_1":"\"test\""`. I am not getting how to escape only json values in java ?

Comment: I already tried `requestData=requestData.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");` but it did not work

Comment: How do you retrieve that `String` ? because you can't just guess which quotes should be escaped at this point, it has to be fixed upstream. As @BackSlash mentioned this isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Aaron I am passing it from UI/html. On HTML console i see value being passed as`{"Attribute_1":"\"Test\"","Attribute_2":"1028"}`. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Aaron I am passing it from UI/html. On HTML console i see value being passed as{"Attribute_1":"\"Test\"","Attribute_2":"1028"}. Which seems to be valid json per https://jsonlint.com/ . So what is wrong here ?

Comment: Yeah the `String` `{"Attribute_1":"\"Test\"","Attribute_2":"1028"}` is valid JSON. Note that to represent this string in java code [you should write `"{\"Attribute_1\":\"\\\"Test\\\"\",\"Attribute_2\":\"1028\"}"`](https://ideone.com/BsWkXQ). What do you mean "passing it from UI/html" ? copy/pasting from a website? If it's a framework please provide a link, with such a name it's an hassle to search on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping it incorrectly. The correct way is that you have to provide the json accordingly, so the compiler can escape the "" for json value.
Write the json String as:

```
String json = "{\"c\" : \"Hello \"Test\" there is a problem\"}";
```

Sample Test Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> tr = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    };
    String json = "{\"c\" : \"Hello \"Test\" there is a problem\"}";
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, tr));
}
```