# Coverting a JavaScript Object in to Json with a double quote(") as a value

Tags: javascript, json, data-conversion

I'm having a problem in converting an object

```
var obj={"Id":"1-AQC1Y1S","Root Order Item Id":"1-AQC1RSA","SC Long Description":"6.5" TXL/Qn/"};
```

In the above object, we have a value like **6.5"** in a string.
Please help me out here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: That's not an array.

Comment: Escape the quote:  `\"`

Comment: `var array1={"Id":"1-AQC1Y1S","Root Order Item Id":"1-AQC1RSA","SC Long Description":"6.5\" TXL/Qn/"}; console.log(array1["SC Long Description"]);` You need to escape the double quotes, simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)

Comment: @Ele Sorry my bad corrected

Comment: I can't add the escape Character manually, any other way?

Comment: Well, if you get this as an output from another program as `JSON` they should update their code since this won't work and will never ... Can you change the output you get from `JSON` to `XML` by using parameters in your request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape it as follow: `6.5\"`

*Once again, that's not an array, is an object instead*

```js
var obj={"Id":"1-AQC1Y1S","Root Order Item Id":"1-AQC1RSA","SC Long Description":"6.5\" TXL/Qn/"};
console.log(obj["SC Long Description"])
```

Assuming that's the fixed structure, you can capture the the groups using a regexp, and make a replacement when the group `"SC Long Description"` is found:

```js
var str = '{"Id":"1-AQC1Y1S","Root Order Item Id":"1-AQC1RSA","SC Long Description":"6.5" TXL/Qn/"}'

var found = false;
str = str.replace(/(".*?")(?!\})/g, function(match) {
  if (found && match.endsWith('"')) return match.substring(0, match.length - 1) + '\\"';
  found = found || match === '"SC Long Description"';
  
  return match;
});

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj["SC Long Description"]);
```

Comment: @AddalaShivateja you're getting that object as string from a thirdparty service?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I have it as a string 
@Ele

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes, simple.

```js
var array1 = {
  "Id": "1-AQC1Y1S",
  "Root Order Item Id": "1-AQC1RSA",
  "SC Long Description": "6.5\" TXL/Qn/"
};
console.log(array1["SC Long Description"]);
```

Comment: I can't an escape Character manually, any other way?
I will be getting that input as a string from another program, so the string value will be changing!

Comment: @AddalaShivateja how will your object look like can you give an example?