# JavaFX-11 in VSCode: Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

Tags: javafx, visual-studio-code, java-11, javafx-11, module-path

I have been trying to set up JavaFX-11 in Visual Studio Code.

I found this post [JavaFX-11 with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode), which explained how to do so, and followed the steps.

However, I need to include the module-path to the JavaFX SDK by adding an entry for the `vmArgs` in the `launch.json` file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - Main",
        "request": "launch",
        "vmArgs": "--module-path C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
        "mainClass": "hellofx.Main",
        "projectName": "hellofx"
    }
]
```

}

As you can see in the `vmArgs` entry, is my local path to the JavaFX SDK. However, when I try to run the program I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

For the past hours I have trying to figure out why it doesn't work. Am I writing the arguments wrong? I saw there are `.jmods` files. Should I download those files? Is there any other way to specify the module path?

Is worth to mention that I am running Visual Studio Code in Windows 10, so I have to use escape sequence to use backslashes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see by the error you have posted:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

it is clear that the issue is related to the space you have in `Program Files`.

**Solutions**

As a possible solution, you could move your JavaFX SDK to a folder without spaces in its path, and set your vmArgs accordingly, like:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path C:\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
```

While that works, if you still want to keep your current approach, you have to find a way to set the path with spaces.

Based on a similar [issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/135), you can find that:

> Paths containing spaces should be surrounded by (escaped) double quotes

So this will be the solution in your case:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
```

Note this doesn't apply to the `path` added in the `.classpath` file with the JavaFX jars, that will be like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib\\javafx.base.jar"/>
```

Comment: Alternate solution would be to use the environment variable PROGRA~1 that delegates to Program Files. e.g. 
`--module-path C:\\PROGRA~1\\Java\\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\\lib`. UNLESS VSCode doesn't support the variables (?)

Answer (score 0):

Adding double quotes surrounding my environment variable in *IntelliJ* solved for me:

```
PATH_TO_FX="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
```

Answer (score -1):

** If you are having this error on Eclipse**
"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found"

Remove the JavaFX SDK library from the build path of the project!!