# Javafx 12 with vscode-java

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I followed the process described in [Javafx 11 with vscode-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode), to set vscode with javafx. It worked for once and i was able to run that sample code [OpenJFX sample code](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/Eclipse/Non-Modular/Java). But after that it is giving me error
 `Error occured during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: UTF-8 -cp C:\Users\... ;.. ;`
In the end is all jar files. How do i make it work?

Comment: you could try to clean the workspace and run again,F1->Clean->Clean the java .....

Comment: I have tried to start with a new project too but it doesn't work. As i understand something in extensions data changes when I run a project. As of I am just working without debugger using terminal to compile and run.

Comment: Try to create the project in the root directory ,don't use too many layers and check the file naming. Do not use unsupported characters

Comment: I just removed all vscode, javafx, extensions etc. and reinstalled all again and the sample code works now.

Answer (score 0):

The repo has dedicated samples for VS Code now: https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/VSCode. Maybe you can take a look at it.