# JavaFx libraries are not worrking at vscode at ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, visual-studio-code

I am new to linux. I downloaded the java jdk and openjfx. When i try to import the javafx.application.Application at vs code i get the following: The import javafx cannot be resolvedJava(268435846). I looked online and could not find the solution. I would like to work at my javafx project that i was coding at windows.

Thanks

Comment: you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353065/10768653),it maybe could help you

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you need to install openjfx package.

You can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is already installed but i do not know why it is not recognised.

Comment: what version of jdk are you using?

Comment: openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)  I have this version. i also installed the openjfx with the same command but vs code does not recognise the libraries of javafx