# javaFX on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a project in java, where I have to implement a graphical interface. I use Visual Studio with an extension that allows i to make java work. Is there an extension, or at least a method, to make JavaFX work on Visual Studio?

when I try to import it

```
import javafx.application.Application;
```

gives me the following error: "The import javafx cannot be resolved"

Comment: If you have above Java 8 or OpenJDK, you'll have to download the JavaFX SDK separately

Comment: That may be not because of VS Code, but because you're using a Java version in which JavaFX is not included anymore by default. It's not included with Java 11 and newer. You will need to download it separately, see https://openjfx.io/

Comment: **Or**, install the [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/) build of OpenJDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode