# Error Occurred During Initialization of Boot Layer for Java FX in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, initialization

I've set the correct launch options in the .json file to my knowledge. I've imported the .jar files of java fx to the referenced libraries folder in VS Code but don't understand why I'm receiving this error. I have imported javafx.controls to the reference library, but still get this error.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

My code is fine with no yellow or red underlines and should compile and run but it is not.

Comment: What is your module path?

Comment: "vmArgs": "--module-path C:/Users/User/Downloads/openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk.zip/javafx-sdk-16/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml", @dan1st

Answer (score 0):

There's no JavaFX and VS Code from its [official tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction), but for all IDEs in Windows, the VM options is like
[image]

You may follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode) to check if there's any environment configuration missed to cause this error.

Comment: @JoshuaMurphy. Please try the answer i mentioned in the update