# JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application on VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

A java newbie here. I wanted to learn about JavaFX on VSCode but when I launch my JavaFX it gave me this error. I tried to add referenced Library and the configurations `vmArgs` on `launch.json` on the project, but it giving me the same thing.

Here is my config.

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path C:/Users/vince/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Not related to your question but. I advise moving the sdk out of the download directory to sonewhete more permanent.

Comment: I don’t know vscode, but comparing your arguments to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode), the arguments look ok, so I don’t know how to fix that.

Comment: @jewelsea i did try to move my javaFX jdk to another place and updated it to VMargs but still same

Comment: You could switch to a jdk that includes JavaFX, e.g. an appropriate version of [liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#mn) or corretto, then you don’t need any arguments, or try idea with the [new project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) which is an easy way to get started.

Comment: A past question like this was solved by [escape quoting the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json), but I don’t think that is your issue here.

Comment: @jewelsea just tried to escape quoting path still same tho

Comment: Set `args` in launch.json, does it help?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT nope, i tried to add vmArgs and im sure the path is correct

Comment: @mcser. After adding vmArgs, please  restart VS Code to make the change effective.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**
You simply need some edits in your "vmAgrs" in the "launch.json" file

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/vince/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

General form of the solution:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"enter_the_path_here\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

Use this and your code should work perfectly.

I was having the same problem and wasted almost 4 hours solving this.
I used this video here: [link](https://youtu.be/_IAEN275WlM)! as reference.
(Caution: the video is in Portuguese)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the samples here: https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/VSCode

You can probably use this [one](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/VSCode/Non-Modular/Java), which I guess is the one you are looking for.

Comment: very useful, thanks

Comment: It would be good if this answer included a code snippet or something in the answer for the bit which makes “ (probably this one) which is suitable for you. ” Pull requests and forks can get deleted which would render this largely link only answer useless.

Comment: I'll update the answer once the PR is merged.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix the javafx in my vs code, but i switched IDE to Eclipse and JavaFX run smoothly after adding VMargs to the run configuration on Eclipse

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this error after setup "vmAgrs", and your using debug/launch-(F5)-to start your App, its possible that VSCode wouldn't launch your "App.java" file, instead  will try to launch "Current file" which is something else..

To fix it just change "Launch Current file" to "Launch App" from "[Start debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)" in "Run and Debug" icon.

---

Anyway if any of this didn't work, you could Run it manually by:

**1st** compile using javac

```
javac --module-path "PATH\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib"  --add-modules javafx.controls App.java
```

**2nd** Run it..

```
java --module-path "PATH\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib"  --add-modules javafx.controls App
```

thanks to Casey [LINK](https://youtu.be/gwZgpH-NV0M)

Answer (score 0):

- Keep your project folder in Workspace and not in a subfolder in Workspace so
  you don't get the class not found error because the path of class file is sets
  "bin" as default in .vscode/settings.json file because of this if you try to
  access App.java file from subfolder in workspace then it throws error.
- If you creates new java file in project then don't forgot to add the below
  line in .vscode/launch.json.

`"vmArgs": "--module-path \"enter_the_path_here_of_lib(Refrenced_Library not  lib present in your project folder)\" --add-modules  javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"`

Answer (score -1):

Try putting everything on one drive other than C.
I had my codes in D drive and JavaFX in C, the codes never launched successfully. It didn't work even when I put the codes in the JavaFX folder.
However, once I transferred JavaFX files to D drive, it worked.