# How to escape double quotes in raw text JSON value string to parse it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to get data from an webpage programmatically. I can extract a string that contains JSON from the page body but sometimes it contains double quotes which are not escaped, because the string has been rendered.
Is there a possibility to use some regex to escape those double quotes? Or any other possibilites?

Example:

```
{
    "rows": [
        ["foobar", "here is my "double quoted" text", "2"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Escaping `"` as `\"` should fix the issue. Make it this `"here is my \"double quoted\" text"`

Comment: I think it's already answerd here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)

Comment: Not really, due to the fact, that I am pulling the data off a website, adding backslashes is by hand is not an option. I searched for an answer for about half an hour, found nothing.
To be more precise I am going to update the question.

Comment: May be helpful if you post the minimal code that you are using to retrieve the data in the first place.

Comment: @benvc I don't think so, it is just `document.getElementById('id').innerText`

Comment: So the element you are getting `innerText` from contains a string representation of the invalid JSON in your example?

Comment: @benvc yes, the request url renders html. It only returns raw data to xhr request, which I can't send or intercept