# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON from API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the following valid json (partially shown), which I have received as a response to an HTTP request (I don't control the server):

`"TotalResults":2,"SearchTerm":"XX","SearchTermClean":"XX","SearchTermExact":"\"XX\"","SearchTermNonExact":"XX","Page":1,"PageSize":100,"TotalPages":1,"TotalTime":0.072,"Filter":"","Sort":"","SortClean":"","IsDesc":false,"PreviousPage":1,"NextPage":1}'`

I'm trying to parse this JSON using:

```js
var json_obj= JSON.parse(helpers.testJSON());
```

where testJSON returns an entire string of json.

I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position 1685
```

which translates to:

```
":"\"XX\""
```

How can I fix this error? I assume I would need to preprocess the JSON before using JSON.parse

Comment: Two things, what's with the blockquotes?  And the object syntax you showed doesn't start with a `{`.

Comment: But `:""XX""` is not valid JSON.  The inner double quotes should be escaped.  `:"\"XX\""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)

Comment: You should really properly format the code block within your question. At the moment, it is unclear whether your JSON is invalid or you have just omitted a portion.

Comment: In order to do so, start your code block with triple backticks (`\`\`\``), optionally followed by the language identifier (in your case `json`) to enable syntax highlighting. End the block also with triple backticks.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Using the backticks is making the json look correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your example. You are using double quotes inside the string. To fix this, you need to escape them with `\`

So your `JSON` will look like this:

```json
{
   "Results":2,
   "SearchTerm":"XX",
   "SearchTermClean":"XX",
   "SearchTermExact":"\"XX\"",
   "SearchTermNonExact":"XX",
   "Page":1,
   "PageSize":100,
   "TotalPages":1,
   "TotalTime":0.072,
   "Filter":"",
   "Sort":"",
   "SortClean":"",
   "IsDesc":false,
   "PreviousPage":1,
   "NextPage":1
}
```

For easy detection of errors in `JSON` syntax, beautify and other useful actions, you can use [this tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: If this is the answer (I think it is) then the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json