# JSON query is not valid

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following query:

```
[{ "type": "url", "value": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail"]}]
```

On running the below code with input as the above query:

JToken.Parse(string query);

I see Invalid JSON query exception

I updated the query to use single quotes for 'displayName:room':

```
[{ "type": "url", "value": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search='displayName:room'&$filter=endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail"]}]
```

With this change, I see Message: Syntax error: character ''' is not valid at position 0 in ''displayName:room'' on making graph call with the url. What am I missing?

Comment: How to escape quotes inside a string depends on what exactly you feed that string to. URLs normally use percent encoding: single-quote is replaced with the 3 characters "%27", double-quote is replaced with the 3 characters "%22". In other situations, doublequote is replaced with 2 characters backslash-doublequote. Related: "[How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json)".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error so maybe it might help someone. I'm working with angular and I had to do this :

```js
_userClient.api('/users')
    .header('ConsistencyLevel','eventual')
    .search('"displayName:' + text + '"')
    .get();
```