# Parse Double Quotes in JSON with Apple Shortcuts

Tags: json, macos-shortcuts

I want to to parse JSON file with Apple Shortcuts. I tried suggestions from [How to escape double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json). So triple `\`:

```
{
    "question" : "I would say \\\"what's the hell happened with quotes?!\\\""
}
```

returns:

[image: picture of the result]

And double `\`:

```
{
    "question" : "I would say \\"what's the hell happened with quotes?!\\""
}
```

returns:

[image: picture of the result]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To parse double quotes in JSON using Apple Shortcuts, you can escape them with a single forward slash as shown below:

```
{
    "question" : "I would say \"what's the hell happened with quotes?!\""
}
```

source: [[link]](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/java/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json.html#:%7E:text=To%20escape%20these%20characters%20in,to%20escape%20the%20double%20quote.&text=If%20you%20are%20using%20a,manually%20escape%20the%20special%20characters)

Comment: Ah, that simple. Why I didn't do it firstly?.. Thank you, It works now perfectly well.