# Created json is invalid due to double quotes present inside line of text

Tags: java, json

In my excel sheet- one of the field is having value - ram and adam  are a sensible,  They have their weekly "play date."

I am trying to convert excel data into json in my java code. Here below is the generated json.
[

```
{

    "ID": "9.0",

    "Description": "ram and adam  are a sensible,  They have their weekly "play date."",

    "Genre": "Comedy"

}
```

]

But if i try to validate this json this is invalid bcoz of “play date” inside value of description field.
Bcoz json itself have quotes n braces.
What should i do now to create a valid json

I tried some regex but did not work

Comment: How did you generate this JSON data?  Please include all steps, all details, and any code.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637429/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-json